# Compare big floating point numbers with it's string equivalent

Tags: php, string, floating-point

Can someone explain why it's not possible to compare big floating point numbers with it's string equivalent:

This example:

```
$f = 1234567890123456789.0;
$s = (string)$f;
var_dump($f, $s, $f == $s);
```

will result in:

```
float(1.2345678901235E+18)
string(19) "1.2345678901235E+18"
bool(false)
```

Why the comparison is false?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems - That's why you compare floating point values using a delta `if (abs($f - $s) < 1.0e-15) echo 'Match';`

Comment: The issue isn't about comparing two floating point numbers as both numbers will be converted into floats in the same way - the first by the compiler and the second by the engine on comparison. The real issue is on loosing precision on convert to string - thanks to @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic:

```
$f = 1234567890123456789.0;
$s = (string)$f;

echo(serialize($f));
echo "\n";
echo(serialize($s));
```

---

```
d:1.2345678901234568E+18;
s:19:"1.2345678901235E+18";
```

Comment: Ah yea that's the issue : the first floating point number looses precision on converting to string. I tested it with ``ini_set("precision", "32");`` than it works fine :) - Thanks!